# access to this array data

Tags: php, laravel, jsondecoder

i have this array result with print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [place_id] => ChIJ7w0gwihoXz4R4F5KVQWLoH0
            [label] => Address Downtown - Sheikh Mohammed bin Rashid Boulevard - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
            [value] => Address Downtown - Sheikh Mohammed bin Rashid Boulevard - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
            [details] => stdClass Object
                (
```

but i need to get place_id property, how i can get this?

i´m trying with `data[0]->place_id` data["place_id"] but always returned me `local.ERROR: Illegal string offset 'place_id'`

**update**

```
if($select == "address"){
                    $aux = $google->getGoogleAddress($select);

                    print_r(json_decode($aux[0]->place_id));
                    /*$this->newData["place_id"] = $aux["place_id"];
                    $google->generateURL($this->newData);*/
```

**SOLUTION**

```
json_decode($aux)[0]->place_id
```

thanks for help

Comment: what was wrong with `$data[0]->place_id`?

Comment: Can you share the actual code? It seems like you might be operating on something different than you think.

Comment: @lagbox this is error with your code: local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'place_id' of non-object

Comment: then this is not the actual data you have

Comment: @El_Vanja i have one return json_encode and i need to access this. i´m doin json_decode and print_r for this, i have result that i have in my question, but i need to acces to place_id, property

Comment: Please *show the code*. Don't describe what you're working with, because that's where the error is - you don't seem to be working with what you think it should be.

Comment: @lagbox i´m doing print_r for return print_r(json_decode($aux[0]->place_id)); and i can see in console, Array of my question

Comment: @El_Vanja you can show it in update

Comment: Well there it is - you can't just decode "in advance". `json_decode($aux[0]->place_id)` should be `json_decode($aux)[0]->place_id`.

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks for help. it´s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the misunderstanding how decoding works. What you're doing:

```php
json_decode($aux[0]->place_id)
```

fails because `$aux` is a string. Which means you're trying to do both array and object property access on it while it's *still a string*.

In order to receive an array, the JSON string needs to be fully decoded first:

```php
$decoded = json_decode($aux);
```

After that, `$decoded` is an array of `stdClass` objects and `$decoded[0]->place_id` should contain what you need. You can, however, do it in one step (in case you don't have to use any other portions of the data):

```php
json_decode($aux)[0]->place_id
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible issue with `place_id` key - it is treated as an array of chars(which causes an error of key accessing).

In order to fix this case - you need to convert result to an array trying one of these workarounds:

1. If this stdClass was retrieved via PDO from database - fetch results as an array instead of an object:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

2. If it was retrieved from other place like file - force casting results to array:

```
$result = (array) $results;
```